# Sorting by dateparts in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, rails-postgresql

So I am using jquery datatables and the column filtering extension to sort, page and filter table date on a Rails project.  One unusual thing about my table is that I need to break up month&day and year components into separate columns and allow searching on filtering on those columns.

So I am looking for help particularly in both searching and sorting for a month/day datepart in a dynamically built ActiveRecord query.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: I'd advise against splitting your date parts into separate columns. Most databases have date functions for this. Eg in Mysql you can do: `Model.order('YEAR(created_at)')` and DAY/MONTH/etc.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, only the display table will show them in separate columns, I intend to keep it as one date in the db.

Answer (score 1):

Rails includes ActiveSupport and a ton of Date helpers.

http://as.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Date/Calculations.html

e.g.

- advance
- ago
- at_beginning_of_day
- at_beginning_of_month
- at_beginning_of_quarter
- at_beginning_of_week
- at_beginning_of_year
- at_end_of_month
- at_end_of_quarter
- at_end_of_week
- at_end_of_year
- at_midnight
- beginning_of_day
- beginning_of_month
- beginning_of_quarter
- beginning_of_week
- beginning_of_year
- change
- end_of_day
- end_of_month
- end_of_quarter
- end_of_week
- end_of_year
- in
- last_month
- last_year
- midnight
- monday
- months_ago
- months_since
- next_month
- next_week
- next_year
- since
- tomorrow
- years_ago
- years_since
- yesterday

The base Date class also has a lot of methods:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html

For instance month, day and year are all available.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of these, but don't think any quite fit me use case.  I don't think my initial post was entirely clear.  I need results ordered out the database as such: 03/31/2000,04/01/2001,04/02/2002.  I realize you can sort by datepart, i.e. Month (as mentioned above), but am not sure how to concatenate two of such for ordering (or some other way to achieve the same thing).  Thanks.